# How reconnect Javascript File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have *index.html*, *Home.html* and *AboutUs.html*

1. index.html: That was a frame for my page
2. Home.html: It has 1 image slider
3. AboutUs.html: It only has text.

My Page starts from index.html. Upon loading, I insert html code for slider to div from Home.html with jquery. It's working.
And when I clicked About Us, I changed html code at div from AboutUs.html with jQuery.It's working too.

But when I clicked back to Home menu, the slider is not working. The Javascript file is disconnected.

I linked all Javascript and CSS file at index.html.

My index.html and Jquery Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>IVORY:SAMPLE ONE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <link href="css/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/generic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#control').load('Home.html #controlHome') ;

            $('#home').click(function () 
            { 
                $('#control').load('Home.html #controlHome') ;
            }); 
            $('#men').click(function () 
            { 
                $('#control').load('Men.html ') ;
            });
            $('#women').click(function () 
            {   
                $('#control').load('Women.html ') ;
            });
            $('#cosmetics').click(function () 
            {   
                $('#control').load('Cosmetics.html ') ;
            });
            $('#accessories').click(function () 
            {   
                $('#control').load('Accessories.html ') ;
            });
            $('#services').click(function () 
            {   
                $('#control').load('Services.html ') ;
            });
            $('#aboutus').click(function () 
            {   
                $('#control').load('AboutUs.html') ;
            }); 

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">           
            <div id="sub_header">
                <h1 id="h1_aaa">I V O R Y - C O L L E C T I O N</h1>
                <br>

                <h2 style="font-family: Monotype Corsiva,sans-serif;font-size: 45;color: #c24678;padding-top:100px;" id="h2_bbb">Make Yours Dream Come True </h2>
                <div class="menu_div">
                    <ul id="menu-bar">
                        <div id="menu_div">
                            <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="men">Men</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="women">Women</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="cosmetics">Cosmetics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="accessories">Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="services">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="aboutus">About Us</a></li> 
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="control">              
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery probably needs to be loaded first. Re-order the `<script>` tags

Comment: Are you sure there is no error in JavaScript after you click "back home"? JavaScript is disabled if there is any runtime error.

Comment: I delete the '#' from Home link, now it's worked. Thank u so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>IVORY:SAMPLE ONE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <link href="css/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/generic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#control').load('Home.html #controlHome') ;

            $('#home').click(function () 
            { 
                $('#control').load('Home.html #controlHome') ;
            }); 
            $('#men').click(function () 
            { 
                $('#control').load('Men.html ') ;
            });
            $('#women').click(function () 
            {   
                $('#control').load('Women.html ') ;
            });
            $('#cosmetics').click(function () 
            {   
                $('#control').load('Cosmetics.html ') ;
            });
            $('#accessories').click(function () 
            {   
                $('#control').load('Accessories.html ') ;
            });
            $('#services').click(function () 
            {   
                $('#control').load('Services.html ') ;
            });
            $('#aboutus').click(function () 
            {   
                $('#control').load('AboutUs.html') ;
            }); 

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">           
            <div id="sub_header">
                <h1 id="h1_aaa">I V O R Y - C O L L E C T I O N</h1>
                <br>

                <h2 style="font-family: Monotype Corsiva,sans-serif;font-size: 45;color: #c24678;padding-top:100px;" id="h2_bbb">Make Yours Dream Come True </h2>
                <div class="menu_div">
                    <ul id="menu-bar">
                        <div id="menu_div">
                            <li><a href="" id="home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="men">Men</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="women">Women</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="cosmetics">Cosmetics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="accessories">Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="services">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="aboutus">About Us</a></li> 
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="control">              
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

script tags needs to be reordered.